# configure intellij idea dialog boxes to be maximized

Tags: intellij-idea

What is the way to configure intellij idea to open the dialog boxes maximized.
Every time a dialog box is opened, by example a new project dialog box, then I have to maximize the window (by double clicking on the title bar) to see the buttons (next, cancel, help). It is extremely annoying. It is everywhere I have to deal with a dialog box into idea.
I use ubuntu 12.04 64 bits. 

[idea project creation](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-mOa2_q_UDTE/UBkhKNWypmI/AAAAAAAACbI/-iS-zN0RgUg/w1150-h647-k/create_new_project.png)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the problem? What's your desktop resolution? What Look&Feel do you use in IDEA? What JDK version/vendor is used?

Comment: I am sorry but I am not allowed to post an image... I don't have 10 rep. points.
1920x1080
allow bedoin theme
1.6.0_33 from oracle

Comment: I added a link to an image. Hope it helps. You can see that the buttons are below what can be seen...

Comment: If the idea dialog box is small then of course no problem... But if it is a large window, then the window is positioned in such a way that I have to maximise it to see the buttons...

Comment: Modal dialogs and wizards do not have maximize option. Please note that IDEA remembers the size and position of the windows. You can try to make this dialog smaller and move it to the top. Then close the dialog and open it again, it should appear in the previous location and retain its size. If it doesn't happen, it's probably your window manager settings that override IntelliJ IDEA behavior and do some additional sizing/positioning.

Comment: It is rather weird... The first time, if I maximize the window and click cancel, the second time I see the window maximized... But if I do it again (a third time), then it is like before (buttons hidden).

Comment: Don't maximize it, just change the size to the comfortable, it should be remembered.